# compare string that contain number base on both charactor and number in string

Tags: java

I want i compare method that compare string that use both character and number to compare

Let say i have 2 string: **s1 = "abc 123"** and string **s2 = "abc 45a"** when use compare method of java i have result s2 > s1 but i want a compare method that return s1 > s2 (because 123 > 45).

For another example **s3 = "def45"**, **s4 = "abc100"** i want compare methode return s3>s4 because d>a
Does java have any built in method like that?

Comment: no java doesn't have a built in method and if you want you can easily write code for it.

Comment: Just use a regex, get the numbers only, and compare them (using a simple subtraction?) 

If you convert the numbres to Integer (object), you can use compare to, but I think that it's like kiling flies with a cannon.

Comment: So, how should `a b 1` and `a b c 2` compare? Does `1` compare to `c` or to `2` here?

Comment: i want "a c 1" < "a b c 2" because 1 < c

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
 private Integer extcartNumberFromString(String str) {
    return Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
  }
```

Example

```
String s = "abc125";
String c = "abc12";
Integer a= extcartNumberFromString(s); // 125
Integer b = extcartNumberFromString(c); //12
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b)); // 1 because a > b
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:

```
public class MyStringComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        // replace digits by ""
        String aLetters = a.replaceAll("\d", "");
        String bLetters = b.replaceAll("\d", "");

        int diff = aLetters.compareTo(bLetters);
        if (diff != 0) {
            return diff;
        }

        // diff == 0 means, that strings are equal

        // replace non-digits by ""
        String aDigits = a.replaceAll("\D", "");
        String bDigits = b.replaceAll("\D", "");

        int aNumber = Integer.parseInt(aDigits);
        int bNumber = Integer.parseInt(bDigits);

        return aNumber - bNumber;
    }
}
```

Now, using `MyStringComparator`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyStringComparator c = new MyStringComparator();
    displayResult(c, "abc 123", "abc 45a");
    displayResult(c, "def45", "abc100");
} 

public static void displayResult(MyStringComparator c, String s1, String s2) {
    int result = c.compare(s1, s2);
    if (result < 0) {
       System.out.println("s1 < s2");
    }
    if (result > 0) {
       System.out.println("s1 > s2");
    }
    if (result == 0) {
       System.out.println("s1 = s2");
    } 
}
```